# Query SPARQL resulting level 1 hierarchy

Tags: sparql, ontology

So, the case is i have an ontology, which contains subclasses and no individual like the picture below.

[image: my ontology]

I want to do a query with SPARQL which will result in level 1 in the hierarchy (subclass of Thing). is that possible to do it?

Comment: yes, it's possible, just check for no other super class expect the top level class aka. owl:Thing (or even its absence)

Comment: @UninformedUser sorry for the late reply. does it still need a reasoning first?

Comment: if you have complex axioms like class equivalence, at least you have consider those as well or simply use a reasoner.

Comment: How about the syntax in SPARQL? i actually try it with `OPTIONAL` to check all subclasses but it still doesn't work and need more running time

Comment: show the query please, I cannot give ayn advice without seing it

Comment: i use this:
`SELECT ?x ?e
WHERE {?x rdfs:label ?y .
 rdfs:subClassOf ?f
 OPTIONAL {?f rdfs:subClassOf ?z .}
 OPTIONAL {?z rdfs:subClassOf ?a .}
 OPTIONAL {?a rdfs:subClassOf ?b .}
 OPTIONAL {?b rdfs:subClassOf ?c .}
 OPTIONAL {?c rdfs:subClassOf ?d .}
 OPTIONAL {?d rdfs:subClassOf ?e .}
 FILTER (regex(str(?y), "sistem informasi","i") 
}`

Comment: i am using 6 times for `subClassOf` because my ontology has at most 6 classes

Comment: I don't know what you're thinking your query does, but this is not what you're asking in your question. 1.) You query is invalid syntax, it has to be `?x rdfs:subClassOf ?f` and even then 2.) it gets subclasses up to depth 6 in hierarchy, but clearly not the "level 1" classes in the hierarchy

Comment: i know it shouldn't be like that. bcs i don't know how to result to subclass of Thing and i'm just trying for all possibilities.

Comment: I don't get it. Subclasses of `owl:Thing` is just `select * where {?cls rdfs:subClassOf owl:Thing}` - but his is not what you want. you just want all classes which do not have a super class besides `owl:Thing`. So, you have to use negation in SPARQL aka `filter not exists`

Answer (score 1):

To allow the questioner to actually select an answer, this from @UninformedUser's comments:

```
SELECT ?cls 
WHERE {
  ?cls a owl:Class .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { 
    ?cls rdfs:subClassOf ?sup .
    FILTER(?sup != owl:Thing) 
  } 
}
```

"this works if all classes are "tagged" as owl:Class"

Comment: What if i include string (`regex` and `str`)? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're saying "find all the things that are subclasses of `owl:Thing` and only subclasses of `owl:Thing` so why not look for all things `rdfs:subClassOf` other things and remove all the non `owl:Thing` matches:

```
SELECT * 
WHERE {
    ?x rds:subClassOf ?y .

    FILTER (!sameTerm(?y, owl:Thing))
}
```

Comment: that is not correct. Your query looks for **instances** of `owl:Thing` because of `a` aka `rdf:type` used in the triple pattern. It would also not be enough to just write `?x rdfs:subClassOf owl:Thing` - by default any class is subclass of `owl:Thing` in OWL. The correct way to get top-level classes is to get all classes that do not have another except (optionally) `owl:Thing` - I'm saying optionally because this trival statement isn't always in the data because it follows from OWL semantics anyways.

Comment: I've changed the `a` to `rdfs:subClassOf` but I still I think @UninformedUser you're right: can you write the correct query out? I see your reasoning in text but can't formulate the correct query.

Comment: the common pattern: `select ?cls where {?cls a owl:Class filter not exists { ?cls rdfs:subClassOf ?sup filter(?sup != owl:Thing)  } }` - this works if all classes are "tagged" as `owl:Class` - if that's not always the case, you could also try to get classes by `?s a ?cls .` triple pattern which also only works of there is instance data. Or maybe, some classes only occur in triples of form `?sub rdfs:subClassOf ?sup .`  - you see, many pitfalls, a complete query should consider all those cases (and maybe even more)

Comment: Ah, so a filter with a subquery which also contains a filter! Nice. Yes, I agree that this query is dependent on uniform `owl:Class` tagging or inferencing being on. I'm hoping to have the rdflib family of tools expanded soon with a backwards chaining reasoner that would build out queries for users. That would cater for this case with `owl:Class` not tagged, but it would use a very long query with all subclasses of `owl:Class` within the target dataset listed in a `UNION` clause