# How to get the top level classes from an ontology with SPARQL and filter out classes restrictions in the query?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, ontology, dbpedia

I know there's some answers from [Query SPARQL resulting level 1 hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60722827/query-sparql-resulting-level-1-hierarchy) and [SPARQL Query - get top-level classes of a dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70886051/sparql-query-get-top-level-classes-of-a-dataset)

But this isn't enough for what I'm trying to do. I have the class Category, subclass of owl:Thing, and the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?cls 
WHERE {
  ?cls a owl:Class .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { 
    ?cls rdfs:subClassOf ?sup .
    FILTER(?sup != owl:Thing) 
  } 
}
```

works fine for other classes without restrictions but it doesn't return Category because Category has restrictions, which this query sees them as separate classes. My Category class looks like this:

```
:Category rdf:type owl:Class ;
          rdfs:subClassOf owl:Thing ,
                          [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                            owl:onProperty :hasConfidence ;
                            owl:minCardinality "0"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger
                          ] ,
                          [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                            owl:onProperty :hasIntensity ;
                            owl:minCardinality "0"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger
                          ] ,
                          [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                            owl:onProperty :hasConfidence ;
                            owl:maxCardinality "1"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger
                          ] ,
                          [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                            owl:onProperty :hasIntensity ;
                            owl:maxCardinality "1"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger
                          ] ;
          rdfs:comment """Category refers to the classification used to annotate the emotion.

This can be further expanded to add support to new categories."""@en ;
          rdfs:label "Category"@en .
```

How can I modify the query to add these top-level classes that are "subclasses" of some restrictions? I need a FILTER for those restrictions but I don't know how to go into this. I tried doing

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?cls 
WHERE
{
   {
  ?cls a owl:Class .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { 
    ?cls rdfs:subClassOf ?sup .
    FILTER(?sup != owl:Thing) 
     }
  }
 UNION 
  { ?cls rdfs:subClassOf owl:Thing }
}
```

and it works but that implies that Category has to be EXPLICITLY subclass of owl:Thing, which isn't always the case in a lot of ontologies.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here's the query for anyone who's having trouble with this like me:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?cls 
WHERE
{
  ?cls a owl:Class .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { 
    ?cls rdfs:subClassOf ?sup .
    FILTER(?sup != owl:Thing) .
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {
          ?sup a owl:Restriction .
         }
    } 
   FILTER(?cls != owl:Thing) # We get rid of the root class from the query results
}
```

Basically, all I needed was a filter for the owl:Restriction class types. I also added a filter to get rid of owl:Thing from the query results. With this query I'm able to get the Category class from my ontology, which is part of the top-layer / level 1 hierarchy.